# How do I create a search against JSON data with input and radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So far I am able to display the data in an HTML page.  However I am stuck when it comes to searching against the Description field and also filtering this data according to Location radio buttons selected.

HTML:

```
 <form>
    <input id="searchterm" type="search" name="query" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="houston">
    <label for="houston">Houston</label>
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="austin">
    <label for="austin">Austin</label>
    <input type="button" name="searchbutton" value="search" onclick=search();>

</form>
```

JSON data:

```
[
{
Description: A bunch of text from which I need to search against
Location: This will be selected by a radio button
}
]
```

Here is what I have tried:
JS CODE:

```
function search() {

    var $searchField = $('#searchterm');
    var query = $searchField.val();

$.getJSON("API LINK HERE", function(data) {

    var output="<ul>";
    $.each( data, function (i, item) {

        output+="<li class='results'><div class='title'><div class='mainCat'>" + data[i].MainCategoryName + "</div>";
        output+="<div class='AdID'>" + data[i].AdID + "</div></div>";
        if(data[i].PhotoUrl !== null){
            output+="<img class='image' src=" + " ' " + data[i].PhotoUrl + " ' " + "></img>";
        }
        output+="<div class='description'>" + data[i].Description + "</div>";
        output+="<button type='submit' class='goToAd' formaction=" + data[i].AdUrl + ">Go To Ad </button> </li>" ;  
    });
        output+="</ul>";
        $("#content").html(output);
});
}
```

Comment: show what you have tried?

Comment: Here is what I have tried:

Comment: For the searching do you want `query` to match (or contain) the text in `data[i].Description` for each `data`? Also is there a `data[i].Location`?

Comment: Yes I would like for the search query to match the text in Data.description.  The Location does not need to be displayed on the search results, but the results should be filtered by Location on search.